# Using bootstrap datetimepicker with knockout js date input field submission issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using knockout js with bootstrap DateTimePicker from here http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#knockout, everything works fine, but the problem is at submission stage that is when I submit the form I can't get the updated value of datetimepicker input field: 
Here is my working HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: params">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="attr: { name: label}, value: value, dateTimePicker: 'date_field'" />

     <button data-bind="event: { click: addParameters } , attr: { class: btn btn-success', href: 'javascript:void(0)'}">Save Settings</button>
</div>
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
function viewModel(data)
{
    // date field observable
    self.date_field  = ko.observable(new Date('2012/12/12'));
    // Observable to track the html form
    self.params = ko.observableArray();
    // when user click by Save Settings button
    self.addParameters =  function(options) 
    {
        var dataparams = self.params();
        console.log(dataparams);
    }    
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);
```

Could anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong? Thank you an advance.

Comment: Please include enough (more) code to reproduce it, and remove any code irrelevant to the question. This makes it a lot easier to help you. See '[mcve]' for guidance if needed.

Comment: self.params() is an empty observable Array. you never add anything to it

Answer (score 0):

I use this datepicker as well.  The module doesn't send the update event to knockout observables.  I do this for each datepicker after initializing it:

```
picker.on('dp.change', function (e) {
    date_field(e.date);
});
```

Comment: Where to add this code? I have added this code in datetimepicker custom binding from here, http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#knockout, but it gives the error "picker is not defined".

Comment: Please include more code in your question to show that you've made an attempt at the solution.  If you're following the documenation for the datepicker you should have somewhere in your code $("#pickerID").datetimepicker().  I will assist further when you update your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in knockout.js v 3.3.1

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    $(element).data('DateTimePicker').setDate(makeStringStandard(value));
    $(element).on('dp.change', function (e) {
        debugger;
        valueAccessor(e.date);
    });
}
```